# Star ratings not expected behaviour

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I understand that I am using the same IDs and names and that what might be causing the issue.

The star rating segment is that:

```
<span class="rating">
  <tr>
    <td>Quality</td>
    <td>
      <span class="rating">
      <% (1..5).each_with_index do |quality, i| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", quality, endorsement.quality == quality, class: 'rating-input', id: "rating-input-1-#{i+1}" %>
        <%= label_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", nil,  class: 'rating-star' %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>
      <span class="rating">
      <% (1..5).each_with_index do |cost, i| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", cost, endorsement.cost == cost, class: 'rating-input', id: "rating-input-1-#{i+1}" %>
        <%= label_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", nil,  class: 'rating-star' %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Time</td>
    <td>
      <span class="rating">
      <% (1..5).each_with_index do |time, i| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", time, endorsement.time == time, class: 'rating-input', id: "rating-input-1-#{i+1}" %>
        <%= label_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", nil,  class: 'rating-star' %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Experience</td>
    <td>
      <span class="rating">
      <% (1..5).each_with_index do |experience, i| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", experience, endorsement.experience == experience, class: 'rating-input', id: "rating-input-1-#{i+1}" %>
        <%= label_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", nil,  class: 'rating-star' %>
      <% end %>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Communication</td>
    <td>
      <span class="rating">
      <% (1..5).each_with_index do |communication, i| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", communication, endorsement.communication == communication, class: 'rating-input', id: "rating-input-1-#{i+1}" %>
        <%= label_tag "rating-input-1-#{i+1}", nil,  class: 'rating-star' %>
      <% end %>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</span>
```

which shows up as:

[image]

I did place some [CSS styles](https://gist.github.com/stefioan/3b5740bd2dfd092c7337) to make it work as expected and it renders as [this (too long to place here)](https://gist.github.com/stefioan/0da05a0edbf28bb464c5).

When I click on any of the stars it just fills one with the certain stars I chose and then I cannot select any other stars from a different rating aspect. I am not that experienced with html tags but a tip or guidance to the right direction will surely get me understand/going.

Comment: Are you using ruby for all the functionality..? meaning every time you click a star, you're making a server request?

Comment: @webkit No. That is a form (simple_form_for) and there is a submit button at the end. The request is send after clicking the button. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: You can get help from http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/LTQrZ/151/

Comment: So what's supposed to color in your stars? are you using javascript?

Comment: I don't quite understand.. If you are looking for a normal star rating behavior, wouldn't you want the stars to fill on hover from the first to the star you're over, and on click they would stay colored on that row.. correct? I don't think you can do this with pure html/css, you need javascript.. do you need help with that?

Comment: @webkit yes that is what I want. However why do I need javascript? Instead of using a simple ratio I use this stars that will hold the value. When I submit the value the form will also be submitted. As for the hover and the coloured styles it works fine. I am using this example http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/star-rating-input-pure-css.html

Comment: @webkit The code I use is gist.github.com/stefioan/86bc79d20885d571e674 and the video showing the current issue is at youtube.com/watch?v=FGsO5NxhZCU

Comment: Cool solution with css, didn't think of it ;] found your problem though, it's in your html.. look below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your problem:

You are using the same **name** to **label for** in your html..

** that's why everytime you click it's affecting only the first line..

fixed [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HQ5gw/)

**EXAMPLE**

In your second .rating span you need to replace this:

```
<input class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-1" name="rating-input-1-1" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="rating-star" for="rating-input-1-1">Rating-input-1-1</label>
```

to this:

```
 <input class="rating-input" id="rating-input-2-1" name="rating-input-2-1" type="radio" value="1" />
 <label class="rating-star" for="rating-input-2-1">Rating-input-2-1</label>
```

Nice solution with css only btw.

Comment: Also, I think your inputs field should be in the opposite order, unless you cover that in your server side code.. meaning right now basically #1 star is on the right and #5 is on the left..

Comment: yeah you are right on that. i noticed when I was debugging

Answer (score 1):

You've named them all the same name: `rating-input-1-`
Change them to different names. `rating-input-2-` etc...

Also - the problem is the difference between the name and id of a radio-button. You probably need to deliberately set the id to, say `rating-input-2-#{i}`, but you also need to set the name for all five stars in the row to just `rating-input-2` ... the name groups the radio-buttons, the id specifies an individual one

eg:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "rating-input-2", cost, endorsement.cost == cost, class: 'rating-input', id: "rating-input-2-#{i+1}" %>
```

Comment: I did try that. However something else happens. Lets say I put 5 stars to Quality... when I click 3 stars for Cost it changes the Quality stars to 3 and it does not give stars to the cost row...

Comment: opk - the problem is the difference between the name and id of a radio-button. You probably need to deliberately set the id to  rating-input-2-#{i}, but you also need to set the name for al five stars in the row to the rating-input-2 ... the name groups the radio-buttons, the id specifies an individual one

Comment: thanks but I am getting a weird behaviour. I cannot really describe or post a screenshot of what happens. Only a video would explain whats going on. I will try to somehow capture my screen and show whats going on on youtube.

Comment: The code I use is https://gist.github.com/stefioan/86bc79d20885d571e674 and the video is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGsO5NxhZCU